# Textured NSWindow with setBackgroundColor has a tinged grey background

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nswindow, osx-yosemite

Basically I want to make a simple about window that has a unified title bar and window (i.e textured) and a white background, like Xcode's about window:
[image: Xcode's about window]

So I have a textured window in IB and I have it connected to my app delegate via bindings. I then add this line of code to the app delegate:

```
[about setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
```

Whilst for other colours like red and blue the window seems to change colour fine, but whenever I use [NSColor whiteColor] the window looks nowhere near as dazzlingly bright as Xcode's window:
[image: My about window :(]

Interestingly enough, when the window is inactive I end up getting Xcode's white colour:
[image: Inactive window]

Is this a bug? Or is it supposed to look really grey? How can I make this window "true white"?

Comment: Did you try `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0, green:0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha:1.0]`

Comment: @trumpeter201 this just makes the window black, did you mean [NSColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1]? It yields the same grey result anyway

Comment: I tried in Xcode 5.1, added `[self.window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and I got a white textured window. Where are you setting the background color ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d I added it in the same place, but this was in Xcode 6 so if it's working fine in previous versions I presume it must be a bug

Comment: Yeah, I did.  It seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Why don't you make it a borderless window? I think it'll be a good idea to make your window borderless, and add close, minimize, and maximize buttons programmatically on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tutorial that uses a pretty darn ghetto hack to swap the frame view's drawRect: method: http://parmanoir.com/Custom_NSThemeFrame

It doesn't even require you to subclass NSWindow, but I did it anyway in case I wanted to use it on another window or something.

The final result:

[image: Yay]

Edit: I submitted a feedback assistant report a while back, and as of either Yosemite DP 7 or Xcode 6.1 this issue seems to be fixed. Setting the background colour of a textured window now produces a non-tinged colour.

Comment: That seems really nice. Do you know if this would be allowed in the Mac App Store?

Comment: @AP. probably not in retrospect but at least its fixed now so you shouldn't have to use this method

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a hacky solution do to this (at least not anymore).

Create a view controller and then open it as a `modal`. In the view controller's subclass code, add this:

```
class YourVC: NSViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Set the background color to white
    self.view.wantsLayer = true
    self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
  }
  override func viewDidAppear() {
    //Customize the window's title bar
    let window = self.view.window

    window?.styleMask.insert(NSWindowStyleMask.unifiedTitleAndToolbar)
    window?.styleMask.insert(NSWindowStyleMask.fullSizeContentView)
    window?.styleMask.insert(NSWindowStyleMask.titled)
    window?.toolbar?.isVisible = false
    window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
    window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
  }
}
```

This is using Swift 3 in Xcode 8.